# How to force httpd to use newer php/php-cgi

Tags: php, debian, httpd, php-cgi

Hi so I have problem dealing with changing PHP version on Debian Wheezy server. It was previously Debian Squeeze with PHP 5.2.17, and I made a dist upgrade and also upgraded everything related to PHP (PHP 5.6.30).

```
    "which php" command gives:
    /usr/local/bin/php
```

Under that path there is executable for php and php-cgi which with "-v" gives 5.6.30

```
   php -v
   php5 -v
   php-cgi -v
   also gives PHP 5.6.30
```

The only path where something is wrong is /usr/local/php5/bin because in that folder ./php gives version 5.2.17 and it is the same version httpd is using somehow. I've tried simply replacing the executables but it gives Internal Server Error.

I've tried also apt-get remove anything php related and reinstall php5 but it won't work either.

There is really strange configuration on this server involving many VirtualHosts and httpd (don't really know, but /etc/init.d/apache2 start/stop doesn't work, only /etc/init.d/httpd start/stop. I can't really change everything there because I won't be able to configure the whole thing from scratch.

Any ideas how to force httpd to use php-cgi 5.6.30 instead of this 5.2.17 old thing?

phpinfo(); returns that CGI/FastCGI is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the PHP is found at `/usr/local/bin`, it means that someone has compiled PHP and Apache themselves, and installed them.

In order to use the distribution's Apache, you need to find where the `httpd` version of Apache and its configuration files are. Then you need to copy the configuration files to `/etc/apache2`.

You might also need to check the PHP configuration files.

It could be best to re-build the configuration from scratch though.

Comment: I've decided to reinstall everything from scratch (including setting up Debian 8 and all configuration). Thanks for confirmation that it was compiled by previous admin by hand.